# My php code is saying I do not have anything in database, although I do. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: php, sql, database

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Tiger-Gen</title>

        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
        .font1 {
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
        <div class=" container center-align font1 y">
        <h1 class="yeet big">Tiger-Gen</h1>
    <?php 
    include ("connection.php");
        $sql= "SELECT account FROM accs";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //output account
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row["account"];
            }
        } else {
            echo "nothing";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?> 

        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn center-align btn-large">Generate</a>
    </div>
    </body>




    </html>

Here is my html and php code, I have read over it many and many times and changed my php code multiple times. As you can see it outputs "Nothing" when nothing is in the database. But the problem is there are things in the database, any help is appreciated.
```

Here is my html and php code, I have read over it many and many times and changed my php code multiple times. As you can see it outputs "Nothing" when nothing is in the database. But the problem is there are things in the database, any help is appreciated.

Database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc1v4.png

Account table:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaEOQ.png)

Comment: Try to echo $result and see what is the output.

Comment: what is code in your connection.php ? does accs table exist in database ?

Comment: also check for `echo mysqli_error($conn);` to see what might be wrong (after query)

Comment: @MahirRawal Didnt show up with anything.

Comment: @DrJManish accs does exist

Comment: @MahirRawal, `$result` is only a pointer.  Echoing it won't have anything in it.

Comment: @Jeff Doesnt show anything

Comment: @MahirRawal what do I use it for then.

Comment: ok... please add connection.php code in question... because nothing wrong seen your current provided code

Comment: Caltexs, your website should have a general error file where Apache/Nginx store runtime errors.  On my server, it's `${DOCROOT}/../logs/error_log`.  Find that file and make it your friend.  It's probably posting an error/warning/notice that will help us.

Comment: what is y class css ??please also check if.. is there attribute display:hidden etc in any class used in div tag

Comment: @DrJManish, why would any of that affect the "Nothing" result the OP is getting?

Comment: @DrJManish yea, I have established its not the css.

Comment: I trust that you have data in yoru database, Caltexs, which is why I'm trying to find that error/warning/notice that's being posted behind your back.  If you can't locate the website error log, do you have the ability to manually run the PHP code?  That should post the error to your screen.  (Finding the error log would be better, it's there....)

Comment: @JBH, haven't used MySQL for a while now.. my bad. Caltexs ... just google how to echo the result of a query and see if you are getting any data from that query ... other alternative is too manually run the query in phpmyadmin to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hey what you are showing here is not the data but the column definition

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaEOQ.png

But what you are querying here is the data in the accs table

$sql= "SELECT account FROM accs";

I believe there is no data in the accs table but you assume the column definition is data

As you are using phpMyAdmin use the browse button to check whether you have any data in the table